# Does c# user authentication based on "System.Security.Principal" works for ADFS and Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, windows-authentication

I am developing a C# WPF application that needs to authorize the current user based on their Windows domain logon. The user is not expected to enter his username/password, the application just authorizes him as long as his user account is running the app.

I achieve this by simply querying the current user's credentials using `System.Security.Principal` like this:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity CallerWindowsIdentity = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
string username = CallerWindowsIdentity.Name;

// Then, I simply look up the username in my database
```

**The problem**: today my client has asked me to make it compliant with users from ADFS (Active Directory Federation Services) and Azure Active Directory.

I'm a bit of an old school coder. My knowledge has been around on-premise Windows Server Active Directory.

Would my code be compliant with these new technologies? Or do I have to redo the logon mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting ADFS will introduce additional overhead. You can try one of the following:

1. Use the MSAL SDK - [Active Directory Federation Services support in MSAL.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-adfs-support)
2. [AD FS OpenID Connect/OAuth flows and Application Scenarios](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-openid-connect-oauth-flows-scenarios)